# select data with count of a phrase in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle10g, string-matching

I have a table say EMPLOYEE and it has a column EMPLOYEE_NAME.
I want to see the phrases which comes in more than 5 records.
The phrase can be anything of 3 characters minimum. 
For example, my table looks like this

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME
User1
User2
User3
Client1
Client2
Client3
Use1
Aent1
Auser2
ent3
```

I want to see 'Use' and 'ent' in the output since they have 5 or more records matching.
 so basically I want to see the character sequences which have a length of 3 which appears anywhere in 5 or more records. 
 let me explain my scenario so that someone can think of a better solution than this. 
 I have a webservice which  will hit a stored procedure in some db. 
 this webservice has a field(say employee name) where we can do wildcard search
this webservice also has another field where we can specify the maximum number of records in the output. 
So if the search result for a particular phrase crosses that number I will get an error in the response.
 I need to find the test data which can give me that error. 
 The query used in sp just puts % before and after the search phrase and returns all d matching records 
 I know the db, table and column which the sp uses and can run any query directly. 
This query solution explained above was the only solution I could think of. 
I haven't tried the answers below since it's already weekend, will try first thing next week. 
But meanwhile if someone could give another better angle of finding the solution, it will be better. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Nothing really. Don't have an idea where to start. Complete blank :)

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format.

Comment: @njk Why?, I think that the question is clear. And just because the user hasn't tried something, it doesn't make it a bad question

Comment: Ok. I didn't know this forum was only for geniuses to clear their doubts. I don't have much experience in sql and couldn't find any related solution after many hours of googling. So instead of pointing the flaws in the question and try to help me out, it will be really useful for me and whoever comes in future with this kind of an issue. Thanks.

Comment: @njk I disagree. The user could have made a research and still don't understand enough to actually try something. I don't think that just because of that, the question doesn't have any value on SO

Comment: @jijo what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I didn't mean to offend anybody. I just felt trying to answer such questions can make this forum useful for clueless people like me too. And its not true that I didn't try anything, I was little embarrassed to show what all I have tried here. I tried so many things which were not worth to be published here as it didn't help finding the solution a little even.

Comment: Do you know which character sequence(s) you want to match up front, or do you want to find and match *any* three-character string that appears anywhere in the row, for 5 or more rows?

Comment: Thats the issue. What I want to know is the character sequence, which can be 3 or more anywhere in the row for 5 or more rows.

Comment: @jijo If you included sample data and expected output it would make any solution much easier to confirm. This [web app](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) can help you do that

Comment: @njk Might be worth looking at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146392/148672) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134381/148672)

Comment: This is an annoying and incompletely framed question but an interesting problem.  Please *edit your question* to include the clarifications you have posted in the comments.  The better you make your question, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sticky point:

> "The phrase can be anything of 3 characters minimum. "

I hope what you mean is you want to scan the table for a given search pattern which can comprise three or more characters.  That's easy

```
select employee_id
           , employee_name
from  ( 
    with data as 
        ( select employee_id
                 , employee_name
                 , case 
                     when instr(employee_name, '&search_pattern ) > 0 
                     then 1 
                   else 0 end as i
          from employees )
    select employee_id
           , employee_name
           , sum(i ) over () as cnt
    from data
    where i > 0 )
where cnt >= 5;
```

Now if what you means is you want to scan through every EMPLOYEE_NAME, establish every set of characters in that text and then search all the other rows for occurences of those patterns, well, then good luck.  I hope you have a raging beast of a server with much RAM and many cores, because you will need a lot of crunch (or a very small table!).

From your comment it would appear that this latter  option is what you want. So, here is a query which will identify all the three-character segements in your code.  You can use this to generate a feed of search patterns which you can feed into the query I posted above.

```
select employee_name, triple from (
    with data as ( select max(length(employee_name)) as mx from employee )
    select employee_name
           , substr(employee_name, level, ,3) as triple
    from employee
         , data
    connect by level <= data.mx )
where length(triple) = 3;
```

In real life you'll want to select just the DISTINCT triples but I left the other column in to provide context for the results.

Extending this solution to find segments of three or more characters is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

---

> "I was hoping to find a simple solution. It amazes me that nobody come
>   across this issue so far."

Well then it's time to wake up and smell the coffee.    [String manipulation is *computationally expensive*.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).  The reason why people spend so much time and money developing database schemas is so we don't have to invest large amounts of effort scanning long strings for ad hoc patterns.

Your scenario is the exact opposite of what we would expect to find in any database.  That's why there isn't a pre-canned solution, let alone a simple one.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I wanted the latter only and I was hoping to find a simple solution. It amazes me that nobody come across this issue so far. I will try this and hope my server will hang itself before hanging me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a pipe row fonction that will return for each string in input n records of every triplet find in input string.
With this (table) function i will make a join with EMPLOYEE_NAME with group by and select only distinct employee name count more than 5.
If you are interested can give you a code example.

Comment: @APC : because i can use the pipelined function like a table and make a join, so i can use a query and not an sql script.

Comment: Have a look at the SQL I posted.  What are you going to do in a pipelined function that can't be done in pure SQL?

Comment: Both work but I think you code is complex with the connect by and can give some headache to some non experienced develloper who has to make this code evolve.Also a function whatever it is can be centralised.

Answer (score 1):

To split the names into phrases of 3 you can use `SUBSTR(employee_name, x, 3)`, where x has to run from 1 to `length(employee_name)-1`:

```
substr('Client1',1,3) Cli
substr('Client1',2,3) lie
substr('Client1',3,3) ien
substr('Client1',4,3) ent
substr('Client1',5,3) nt1
```

To generate those positions, one could create a table containing the numbers of 1 to max. Or use a bit of magic and generate the numbers on the fly:

```
SELECT level AS x FROM dual CONNECT BY level < max;
1
2
...
```

Combined, this gets all the phrases of length 3 of all employee names:

```
SELECT id, substr(employee_name, x, 3) AS phrase
  FROM employee
  JOIN (SELECT level AS x FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 27) pos
    ON pos.x < length(employee_name)-1;
1 Use
1 ser
1 er1
...
```

Now we only have to filter out the phrases that occur in 5 or more rows. That's easily done by a `GROUP BY phrase HAVING count(DISTINCT id) >= 5`:

```
SELECT phrase, count(distinct id)
  FROM (
        SELECT id, substr(employee_name, x, 3) AS phrase
          FROM employee
          JOIN (SELECT level AS x FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 27) pos
            ON pos.x < length(employee_name)-1
       )
 GROUP BY phrase
HAVING count(distinct id) >= 5;
ent 5
```

Why should 'Use' be in your example result? I's only in 4 rows?

Comment: Missed one thing, checking the matching the records should be case insensitive. That will make 5 'use' right.